# Find inf and sup for $\{a + {1 \over {2a}}: a\in Q, 0.1 \leq a \leq 5\}$

Tags: real-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Find the $inf$ and $sup$ for $\{a + {1 \over {2a}}: a\in Q, 0.1 \leq a \leq 5\}$

I took a = 0.1 and a=5, the value is 5.1
and when a = 0.5 or a = 1, the value is 1.5

Comment: what is $$0.1>a>5$$?

Comment: sorry, typed a wrong relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using $AM-GM$ we get $$a+\frac{1}{2a}\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: got you. thanks!